# iOS app randomly crashing pointing to thread: _pthread_wqthread

Tags: ios, swift

I'm having a problem with an app that handles users' photos. I've looked around and those who've had similar problems at similar locations had problems with accessing data from the device. I've looked through everything and I have no idea what the problem could be. This is the code for the function that fetches an array of the user's photos. Could this be the problem?

```
init() {
    PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization { (status) in
        switch status {
        case .authorized, .limited:
            self.errorString = ""
            self.getAllPhotos()
        case .denied, .restricted:
            self.errorString = "Photo access permission denied"
        case .notDetermined:
            self.errorString = "Photo access permission not determined"
        @unknown default:
            fatalError()
        }
    }
    
    updatePhotos()
}

fileprivate func getAllPhotos() {
    let manager = PHImageManager.default()
    let requestOptions = PHImageRequestOptions()
    requestOptions.isSynchronous = false
    requestOptions.deliveryMode = .highQualityFormat
    let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
    fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)]
    
    let results: PHFetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .image, options: fetchOptions)
    if results.count > 0 {
        for i in 0..<results.count {
            let asset = results.object(at: i)
            let size = CGSize(width: 700, height: 700) //You can change size here
            manager.requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: size, contentMode: .aspectFill, options: requestOptions) { (image, _) in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    if let image = image {
                        let betterImage = BetterUIImage(image: image, asset: asset)
                        if i == 0 {
                            self.currentRenderedPhoto = betterImage
                        } else if i == 1 {
                            self.preRenderedPhoto = betterImage
                        }
                        self.allPhotos.append(betterImage)
                    } else {
                        print("error asset to image")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.errorString = "No photos to display"
        }
    }
    print("getAllPhotos() completed")
}
```

Edit: It's a memory leak, looking into it now.